# Syntax error in Vba-excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have one sheet each in two different workbooks. Both sheets are same, except that sheet 2 has 3-4 records more. I use a left join to get the those records but getting an syntax error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. 
Eg:-

```
Workbook1     Workbook2
Sheet 1       Sheet 1

ID  Name      ID Name
123  Jim      123  Jim
255  jack     255  jack
275  alice    275  alice
300  Bob
```

so as you see first one has 4 records and second one has 3, which will be always the case. I just need to find that extra record in first sheet and record.

```
Sub get_unknowns()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set x = Workbooks.Open("A.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("B.xlsx")

With cn
.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
.Open
End With

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [x.Worksheets("Sheet1")] LEFT JOIN [y.Worksheets("Sheet1")] ON [x.Worksheets("Sheet1")$].[PrimaryID] NOT IN " & _
"[[y.Worksheets("Sheet1")$].[primaryId]", cn

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

As suggested I made some changes and tried, I have two sheets in the same workbook and trying to use a left join

```
Sub get_employees()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "H:\testing\demo\test1.xlsx;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0"";"

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] as A LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] as B ON A.[Id] =B.[Id]", cn

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Now its throwing a Run time error 3709 that the connection cannot be used to perform this operation. it is either closed or invalid in this context.

Comment: Look at your path in the connection string: `"Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "H:\testing\demo\test1.xlsx;"` That's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string appears to be incorrect and you havent opened the connection. Try something like this

```
Sub get_employees()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        .Open
    End With

    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] as A LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] as B ON A.[Id] =B.[Id]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are several issues:

a) You cannot open an xlsx file with JET, you need ACE, like:

```
  cn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Workbookname.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0"";"
```

b) You don't need to open the workbooks in VBA; the connection does that on its own, but:
c) The connection counts only for one workbook. I don't think cross-workbook-queries are possible.
d) The syntax for a table in the `FROM` part is `[Sheetname$]`, you must fill this correctly into the string (the name of a VBA variable won't help inside the query string). This sheet must be in the workbook that is opened through the connection string.